# remove sublist from certain element (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary with lists of lists. I would like sublists that have a certain `''` element to be removed.

Below I put how I'm trying to forward this. I'm having trouble removing the entire list. In the code below the element `''` has been removed

```py
d = {'af':[['info01','info02'],['info03','info04'],['info05','']]}
print(d['af'])

af2 = any('' in sublist for sublist in d['af'])
af_final = [[element for element in sub if element != ''] for sub in d['af']]


if af2:
  d['af'] = af_final

print(af_final)
```

#### Output (prints)

```
[['info01', 'info02'], ['info03', 'info04'], ['info05', '']]
[['info01', 'info02'], ['info03', 'info04'], ['info05']]
```

#### I would like the output to be

```
[['info01', 'info02'], ['info03', 'info04']]
```

Comment: What *should* the output be?

Comment: @ScottHunter add to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for something like this:

```py
d = {
    'af':[
        ['info01', 'info02'],
        ['info03', 'info04'],
        ['info05', ''],
    ]
}
print(d['af'])
# [['info01', 'info02'], ['info03', 'info04'], ['info05', '']]

af2 = any('' in sublist for sublist in d['af'])

af_final = [sublist for sublist in d['af'] if '' not in sublist]

if af2:
  d['af'] = af_final

print(af_final)
# [['info01', 'info02'], ['info03', 'info04']]
```

Comment: thanks! I was iterating the elements of the sublists. your code iterates through the sublists looking for the `''` element, correct?

Comment: Exactly. Every sub-list is checked whether it contains `''` as an item and only if it *doesn't* the sub-list is added to the main list